# How do I revert back to stock recovery after unrooting on Nvidia Shield Tablet

Tags: recovery-mode, unrooting

I need to update my Nvidia Shield Tablet (running  Android 5.0.1) to the latest version so that I can check if it contains a faulty battery type. To update I presume that I needed to remove root access and CWM that I installed using a guide.

I have ran a full unroot on SuperSU. Now, all that is left is to return to the stock recovery. How do I do this?

The guide I used is [here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-root-nvidia-shield-tablet-android-5-0-lollipop-install-cwm-recovery-1481041).

Answer (score 1):

No need to unroot or to flash stock recovery. I dont have the link to the LTE version, but this is for the WIFI ONLY tablet, you can download the OTA from [here.](http://international.download.nvidia.com/ota/rom/productionBL-droid-signed-wx_na_wf-full_ota-35398_567.2193.20150708141951.zip) And flash using your favorite custom recovery. I did this last night and I flashed it through TWRP no problems, It took a little longer than normal to flash, but it did go through after about ~3 mins. On a side note, mine is one of the recalled ones. =(

You can find all of the OTA's for both the LTE and WIFI [here.](https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworksdownload) You do have to sign up, but it was quick and painless to sign up.

Edit: For those that are wondering, After I flashed the OTA via TWRP. I flashed Supersu and had root when I booted the tablet back up.

Edit2: After some more digging and reading, it appears that all the wifi only versions of the tablet use the same firmware, Only the LTE images are different for the US and the rest of the world.

Comment: I upvoted this because I had your idea in mind too when I edited that post, but OP seems to be in other direction. I say you advise OP to somewhat edit the post and allow your answer to become perfectly valid, though it's not invalid of course, as of now at least. :) Although it's odd to me how updating would help in checking the faulty battery type, which is the objective to achieve. Any ideas.

Comment: @Firelord From what I was reading. Installing the update enables another field in the battery section of the settings > about device > status. To let you know if your batter is Y01 or B01. Y01 seems to be faulty. They also built in a recall "form" that's needed to start the recall process. Furthermore, it seems the update adds a remote kill switch. At least that's what I understand from the RMA email I got from Nvidia. **As a reminder, when you set up your new tablet, your old tablet will be deactivated and no longer function.**

Comment: I haven't had any problems with heat or anything. I am hoping maybe I can put a custom rom on the tablet before turning on the new one and bypass the remote disable that way... =p